# Raspbian can not be update properly

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-14.04, raspbian

Suddenly my RaspberryPi can not be upgrade properly. The apt gives following error message. Is there anyone could me how to fix this problem. 
   Following is the error message

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess tar was killed by signal (Segmentation fault)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 250, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 108, in main
        pkg = DebianFiles.Package(deb)
      File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 134, in __init__
        self.binary  = pkgdata.Package
    AttributeError: ControlStanza instance has no attribute 'Package'
```

Comment: take a look at this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51094/multiple-segmentation-faults

Answer (score 0):

i have already found the reason and fixed the problem.

step

1) use this command to catch the trace log.

```
 sudo strace -f -e trace=execve apt-get -y upgrade > execlist 2>&1
```

2) check the execlist file and notice following error message

```
[pid 27534] execve("/usr/local/sbin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27534] execve("/usr/local/bin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27534] execve("/usr/sbin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27534] execve("/usr/bin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27534] execve("/sbin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27534] execve("/bin/tar", ["tar", "-x", "-m", "-f", "-", "--warning=no-timestamp"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
[pid 27533] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 27532] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 27531] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=27533, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 27534] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x638aa} ---
[pid 27534] +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

3) it seems something wrong with the program tar.

4) download a new tar program on another server and replace it.

the problem solved.